# How many rectangles can be found in a 5 x 5 square? Diagonal rectangles are allowed.

Tags: combinatorics, rectangles

In a 5 x 5 square, there are 225 rectangles, but what if I allow for rectangles that are diagonal? How many more rectangles would I have? Here is an example of a diagonal rectangle:
[image]

Comment: Either (A) the Answer is contained in your Question itself Or (2) the Question is Incomplete. (A) If you somehow want to make new rectangles and add to the total, naturally the total number changes or increases (B) To calculate the new total , you should Explain what you mean by "Diagonal rectangles" by including a Diagram and showing some Examples of those "Diagonal Rectangles" which gives the Detail.

Comment: I added a picture. I hope this clarifies :)

Comment: Have you tried a brute force approach by beginning with each vertex and considering all possible diagonal configurations? You can ignore the 4 far corners of the grid and then maybe try to appeal to symmetry for counting the number of possible rectangles.

Comment: I am looking for a combinatoric approach to this problem :)

Comment: I am not sure where the number $225$ comes from, isn't it $100$? Also, what about a rectangle (square) $(0,1),(2,0),(3,2),(1,3)$ with sides $\sqrt{5}$, which is not straight but is also not "diagonal"?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799010/how-many-rectangles-can-be-made-within-the-confines-of-a-5-times-5-square) for more info :) I am quite certain that it is 225. The square you are talking about classifies as "diagonal" for this case, and should still be counted in the final answer :)

Comment: @CoderCookie10 Do you mean $5$ dots by $5$ dots (as in your picture); or length $5$ by length $5$ (which is $6$ dots by $6$ dots), as in the question you link to in your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be found at [OEIS A085582](http://oeis.org/A085582) and for $n=5$ the answer is $130$.

Or, as I see, you're allowing rectangles where the "side length is $0$" i.e. the corners reside at same point. Would then a non-axis-aligned rectangle also be allowed to be "just a line"? If not, add the number of non-axis-aligned, from [A113751](http://oeis.org/A113751) (for $n=5$ it's $30$) to the axis-aligned number to get

$$225 + 30 = 255.$$

If you also allow degenerate diagonal rectangles, read on.

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comments, the degenerated rectangles are simply counted by choosing two points from the square (we can even choose the same point to just get a point as the rectangle). So it is

$${n^2\choose 2} + n^2 = \frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}.$$

Add this to the number of non-degenerate rectangles given by [OEIS A085582](http://oeis.org/A085582). For $n=5$ we get

$$130 + 325 = 455.$$

(That's what I get with my brute force program too.)

Comment: With side=0,  we can include each of the 25 Points and include each of the lines from one Point to some other Point 25x24/2 , giving 325 "zero area" rectangles ! With the "non-zero area" rectangles, total is going to be even more !

Comment: @Prem Yeah, that's easier way to count the degenerate ones. Then just add the non-degenerate from http://oeis.org/A085582 (that is $130$). So $455$ in total.